# Sqlite threaded design

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am creating application which uses sqlite to store some key value pairs.Now I dont want to block the main thread for performing sqlite operations.I have created separate thread for sqlite operations and created a queue for all operations. Main thread tell sqlite thread to do various oprerations. For each sqlite operation sqlite thread create a task and add to its queue .Main loop of sqlite thread takes task from queue and process it.

Now issue is that main thread cannot proceed until its get data from sqlite.So does it makes sense to have separate thread for sqlite operations?

Can I do this is some better way so that my main thread remains unblocked and it can get sqlite data also?

Comment: I would say that if your main thread must wait for result, there is no advantage in in having SQLite operations in other threads. Maybe other tasks in which main thread doesn't depend should be in other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. For example, you can have some function getResult() which will return concurrent container which you will use in your main thread. It allows to add new data as long as it is extracted from a DB and on the other side to get data as soon as it is available and do not wait until whole result is ready.
For concurrent containers you can try the following libraries: [PPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx), [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) or [Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree.html).

Also you can use some event-driven programming by sending events from your work thread to your main thread. Boost.Signals could be of help in such a case.

One more thing: you can use asynchronous programming by using PPL::task, for example. You create task to get result from the DB and set continuation to handle this result. No block.

I believe there are other variants as well. So it is up to you to choose what is better suited for the task